# Web Scraping Selenium , Multiple pages and product issue

Tags: python, html, css, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i am doing scraping using selenium but not able to get all the href of 25 pages and all 626 products listed by getting all the href of products and multiple features from product and i want to scrape all the products on the 25 pages .
but while extracting all the 25 pages href it only gives 1 to 7 then jump to 25 directly not able to get all 25 pages links . and product listed there.

then i click on product link by sending keys and storing the href of all the products in url of pages .

````
import selenium
import pandas as pd 
from selenium import webdriver
import getpass, time
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException, ElementNotVisibleException,StaleElementReferenceException

#First we will connect to webdriver
driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'/Users/ankit/chromedriver')
#Open the webpage with webdriver
driver.get('https://www.getapp.com/hr-employee-management-software/human-resources/')om/hr-employee-management-software/human-resources/')
URL2 = []  # for product pages
URL = []  # for storing all the pages
URL3=[] # for storing all video links
for i in range(1, 28):
    URL.append(
        f"https://www.getapp.com/hr-employee-management-software/human-resources/page-{i}/")
   # visiting all the pages and scraping the products/Read More About... Links
for p in URL:
    driver.get(p)
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//a[@data-testid="listing-item_text-link_read-more-about-product"]'
    ):
        URL2.append(i.get_attribute("href"))

for i in URL2:
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(
            driver, 5
        )  # time waiting for element to be found or accessable [Wait variable use below]
        driver.get(i)  # going through each page
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'ytimg')]")
        for element in elements[0:1]:
            while True:  # making videos properly available for clicking the  right arrow
                try:
                    element.click()
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    elemt = wait.until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                            (By.XPATH, '//button[@data-evac="slide-to_right"]/div')
                        )
                    )
                    elemt.click() 
                    time.sleep(0.7)

            driver.implicitly_wait(3)
        try:
            URL3.append(
                 driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//iframe[contains(@id,"yt-player")]'
                ).get_attribute("src")
            )  # collecting and adding it up
        except NoSuchElementException:
                 URL3.append('--')
                 elemt = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@title="Close"]'))
            )
                 elemt.click()  # finally closing
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed" ,e, i)
#we will open 1st  product link  to get all the necessary paths.
click=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/a/p").click()

NAME=[]
OVERVIEW=[]
Image_url1=[]
Image_url2=[]
Image_url3=[]
Image_url4=[]
Image_url5=[]
#extracting and storing the Features of the product
FEATURE1=[]
FEATURE2=[]
FEATURE3=[]
FEATURE4=[]
FEATURE5=[]
PRICING=[]
for i in URL2:
    driver.get(i)
    try:
        name=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/h2/span")
        NAME.append(name.text.replace('product overview', '-'))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        NAME.append('--')
    try:
        overview=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p')
        OVERVIEW.append(overview.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        OVERVIEW.append('--') 
    try:
        i=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img")
        Image_url1.append(i.get_attribute("src"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Image_url1.append('--')
    try:
        i=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[1]/img")
        Image_url2.append(i.get_attribute("src"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Image_url2.append('--')
    try:
        i=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/img")
        Image_url3.append(i.get_attribute("src"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Image_url3.append('--') 
    try:
        i=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div[3]/img")
        Image_url4.append(i.get_attribute("src"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Image_url4.append('--')
    try:
        i=driver.find_element_by_tag_name("img")
        Image_url5.append(i.get_attribute("src"))
    except NoSuchElementException:
        Image_url5.append('--')
    try:
        feature1=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/div")
        FEATURE1.append(feature1.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        FEATURE1.append('--')
    try:
        feature2=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div")
        FEATURE2.append(feature2.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        FEATURE2.append('--')
    try:
        feature3=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div")
        FEATURE3.append(feature3.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        FEATURE3.append('--')
    try:
        feature4=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div[4]/div")
        FEATURE4.append(feature4.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        FEATURE4.append('--')
    try:
        feature5=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[3]/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div")
        FEATURE5.append(feature4.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        FEATURE5.append('--')
    try:
        Pricing=driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/p[1]")
        PRICING.append( Pricing.text)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        PRICING.append('--')  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are not getting all the pages because the pagination is dynamically loaded on the website. You need to click on the pagination to load the other pages(and the href/link of those pages).

But a smart way would be to make the URLs manually rather than scraping because they are similar.
like this :

```
URL =[]
for i in range(1,27):
    URL.append(f"https://www.getapp.com/hr-employee-management-software/human-resources/page-{i}/")
```

I understood that your next goal is to click on the *Read More About...*. But here is what you are doing wrong/ making some inefficient approach. After entering the first page, you immediately clicked on the *Read More About ...*.
Instead, scrape all the *Read More About...* links **PER PAGE**. Then visit these scraped links one by one for the features.

Here is my complete approach:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())


URL2 = []  # for product pages
URL = []  # for storing all the pages

for i in range(1, 27):
    URL.append(
        f"https://www.getapp.com/hr-employee-management-software/human-resources/page-{i}/"
    )

# visiting all the pages and scraping the products/Read More About... Links
for p in URL:
    driver.get(p)
    for i in driver.find_elements_by_xpath(
        '//a[@data-testid="listing-item_text-link_read-more-about-product"]'
    ):
        URL2.append(i.get_attribute("href"))



# then collect the features by visiting the URL2 list
```

It seems like videos are at the end of the preview section, and the links for the videos are not visible directly. They are available when they are clicked because they are embedded.

To achieve our goal, we can take these steps.

- Make them properly visible for clicking
- Click on the videos (Some Products have multiple)
- Extract Links from the iframe.
- Close the video preview panel (because products that have multiple videos need to be properly visible before clicking the other video ).

Code for this approach(steps explained with comments)

```
for ul in URL2:
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(
            driver, 5
        )  # time waiting for element to be found or accessable [Wait variable use below]
        driver.get(ul)  # going through each page
        elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//img[contains(@src,'ytimg')]")
        for element in elements[0:1]: # use limit here for number of video links
            while True:  # making videos properly available for clicking the  right arrow
                try:
                    element.click()
                    break
                except Exception as e:
                    elemt = wait.until(
                        EC.element_to_be_clickable(
                            (By.XPATH, '//button[@data-evac="slide-to_right"]/div')
                        )
                    )
                    elemt.click() 
                    time.sleep(0.7)

            driver.implicitly_wait(10) 
            URL3.append(
                driver.find_element_by_xpath(
                    '//iframe[contains(@id,"yt-player")]'
                ).get_attribute("src")
            )  # collecting and adding it up

            elemt = wait.until(
                EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '//div[@title="Close"]'))
            )
            elemt.click()  # finally closing
    except Exception as e:
        print("failed" ,e, ul)
```

**NOTE**: In the case of iframe (in selenium) we need to switch to the iframe or handle it in a diffrent way. But luckily for you video links are available outside the iframe.

[image: Iframe HTML]

Comment: One more thing sir if i need to get the video URL from the different products i am not able to extract it as it only extract the href of the thumbnail of the video .

Comment: added that too. please check

Comment: ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element <img class="Image jss296" alt="Feature image" src="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/ba93MkLhGpw/hqdefault.jpg" data-hj-ignore-attributes=""> is not clickable at point (127, 448). Other element would receive the click: <button class="jss289 jss290" data-evca="product_media" data-evla="slider-arrow" data-evac="slide-to_left" data-testid="carousel-slide-left" data-hj-ignore-attributes="">...</button>
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.41)

Comment: this error is coming

Comment: Please check once @MahmodulHaque

Comment: Please look into it once @MahmodulHaque

Comment: i looked into it .. i need some time. there reason the error is throwing because some elements get blocked while clicking the arrow on the bottom pannel. i will work on it when I am free.

Comment: Ok sure i don't need to extract all the videos that are present in 1 product  just 1 video per product is fine . @MohmodulHaque

Comment: Did you able to find the way to get it ? @MohmodulHaque

Comment: added the update. it collects all the links. you can limit it too

Comment: Can you help me with if i have to limit only one video for 1 product so that my data frame didnt get messy .@MahmodulHaque

Comment: or is there any way i can sort all the videos in the product they are present . cause because of this my length of index gets messy nd if i limit the no.of video links to display . all the links gets unstructured not according to the product name they comes in different order. @MahmodulHaque

Comment: you can create and dictionary in python and store the links in that, other things to structure your data
updated with the limit

Comment: ok thats helping

Comment: sorry for disturbing you more . i need to get the first five images link but only those images link which opens  in full screen . i was able to get all the images link for first 5 for all the products . but not able to sort or move through or exclude the short images. can you help in this if you have time @MahmodulHaque

Comment: 1st some of the products don't have 5 images
2nd which image is short and which is not? give some examples

Comment: Like some images are not full screen like width nd hight wise

Comment: Those products which doesn't have 5 images m using exception there no issues about that it's just some of the images are not full screen @MahmodulHaque

Comment: Or if you don't find my explanation conclusive leave it cause i also know it's so hard to explain . Just help me with one thing atleast.        ```While i am scrapping for the product overview text it scrapes most of the products overview but leave few products i don't know but the xpath for all the product overview extraction is Same but still it leave few products .

Comment: ``` OVERVIEW=[]
for i in URL2:
   driver.get(i)
   try:
       overview=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="__next"]/div[2]/div[2]/section[1]/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[2]/p')
       OVERVIEW.append(overview.text)
   except NoSuchElementException:
       OVERVIEW.append('--')    ```.  @MahmodulHaque this is what xpath i m using

Comment: if you have time can help you build the full project[free] as much as I can in my spare time.  you can hit me on discord or Instagram.

I cant basically say why you are not getting the product overview without running the full script.

what you can do is run the script in debugging mode and see it one by one. Or use make a condition to stop if there is no overview and then find out why ? use the try-except block

Comment: can we connect on discord  BIXBITE#3133 this is my  discord id , you can send me yours.  and ankit.6380  this is my insta username   . can you share me yours will send you request . @MahmodulHaque

Comment: for your reference i have updated whole block of code that i am running @MahmodulHaque

Comment: check discord. sent a request. Can u share the full script, if don't mind?

Comment: shared you everything @MahmodulHaque